# How to prevent JAXB from checking ObjectFactory class

Tags: xml, jaxb, marshalling, classloader

My classloader complains

```
Unable to find class resource 'com.d.xml.ObjectFactory'
```

every time I marshal objects to XML.

Mapping defined with annotations.

Is it possible to configure JAXB to avoid checking ObjectFactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating your JAXBContext on a context path (package name), then you can avoid the need for an ObjectFactory class by providing a text file called `jaxb.index` with a carriage return separated list of class names.  For an example see:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

Alternatively you can create a JAXBContext by passing in the domain classes:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class, Bar.class);
```

Comment: Hi @Blaise, I've already read about jaxb.index, but it's not very good because any updates on class-list needs an update of jaxb.index. Also passing domain classes explicitly to the JAXBContext doesn't look very convenient.

Comment: @Vladimir - The core of the issue is that there isn'ta Java API to get the classes from a particular package.  To get around this a JAXB impl will look for an ObjectFactory class (since it has a known name), and determine the domain objects from it.  The alternatives are to supply the list of domain objects, either via jaxb.index or an array of classes.

Comment: Thanks so much, for quite detailed explanation as usual.